# NSURLSession task cancellation issue (CFNetwork internal error)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, cfnetwork

I'm receiving error messages in log:

> CFNetwork internal error 0xc01a:/SourceCache/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-711.1.16/Connection/URLConnectionLoader.cpp:1321)

The problem is something to deal with cancellation of `NSURLSessionDataTask` objects under extreme pressure (tasks are created and cancelled very fast). The error doesn't occur when tasks aren't cancelled. And it's also doesn't occur when tasks are cancelled with a delay:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.25 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [_task cancel];
});
```

Apple has stopped providing a [CFNetwork](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CFNetwork/) source a long time ago. How someone go about debugging this kind of error?

Comment: You'll need to show the relevant code (i.e. code related to creation and cancellation of connections etc.).

Comment: Ok, so I removed everything that was not related to the issue from the source code and updated the answer. It's still reproduces.

Comment: I did "fix" the problem by introducing a command class that resumes or cancels NSURLSession tasks; and command executor that serially  executes those commands with a constant interval (one command each 3 ms). It also helped me improve performance on outdated devices and reduce NSURLSession trashing.

Comment: This question remains open though, maybe someone has more insight.

Comment: By any chance are you canceling the request right after you start it without allowing the main run loop to run in between?  If so, you might effectively be trying to stop the task before it actually starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution to this problem - you should rate limit the requests. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Token_bucket `URLSession` just isn't designed to be used like that.

Answer (score 1):

You  could put  code here exception. Also take NSError class to find what error occur during networking task.